# GCM http Authentication Error Parse Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, authentication, parse-platform

I am sending POST requests from my backend, but I am getting a 401 authentication error.

I am sending:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'key=AIz...',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: {
      "to": REG_TOKEN,
      "collapse_key": "notif",
      "notification": {
          "title": "Notification",
          "body": "this is a noisy test"
      }
   },
   success: function (httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
   },
   error:function (httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
   }
});
```

Where AIz... is my server key.

I get:

```
Request failed with response code 401
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have followed all the troubleshooting steps but I am still not able to fix this. The problems are as follows:

Authentication Error

The sender account that you're trying to use to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:

1. Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax.
2. Invalid project number sent as key.
3. Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
4. Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.

I am have authentication in my header, I am using the server key for GCM, the service is enabled, and the key is currently unrestricted for testing, so there should be no need for whitelisting.

Any advice would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: There should not be a `'` before `key` in your header. It should be like `'Authorization: key=AI...',`.

Comment: That gives me a syntax error :(